# Autohotkey variable does not get expanded, simple but baffling

Tags: autohotkey

Please help check my Autohotkey(1.1.13.01) script:

```
#!r:: Reload
Sleep 1000
MsgBox, 4,, The script could not be reloaded. Open it for editing?
IfMsgBox, Yes, Edit
return

global gg := 10

#!t:: MsgBox % "gg= " . gg

myMsgBox(text)
{
     MsgBox % "mynum:" . text
}


#!y:: myMsgBox(%gg%) # gg does not carry 10 into myMsgBox
```

No matter Alt+Win+t or Alt+Win+q does not show variable expansion. I hope to see `gg=10` in MsgBox but I only see `gg=`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are to be defined in the auto-execute section:

```
global gg := 10

#!r:: Reload
Sleep 1000
MsgBox, 4,, The script could not be reloaded. Open it for editing?
IfMsgBox, Yes, Edit
return

#!t:: MsgBox % "gg=" . gg

#!y:: myMsgBox(gg)

myMsgBox(text){
MsgBox % "mynum:" . text
}
```

Comment: OK. Search the manual for ``auto-execute`` and got the idea.

Comment: One more question: If I ``#Include customize.ahk`` after ``global gg := 10`` and ``#!r:: ... return``, is it still possible to override ``gg``'s value in ``customize.ahk`` ?

Answer (score 2):

You should also add the Reload command on a new line otherwise the lines below it will not be executed.

```
#!r:: ; new line here 
Reload
Sleep 1000
; ... rest of your script
```

To have more than one command executed by a hotkey, put the first line beneath the hotkey definition and make the last line return. See http://ahkscript.org/docs/Tutorial.htm#Launch

Comment: I'm afraid you are not talking right, and not talking related to my question.

Comment: In your script the lines below your reload hotkey #!r (the lines with sleep 1000, MsgBox etc) will never be executed. I assume you meant to make #!r a multiline hotkey? If so you need to add a new line - read the documentation I linked to. I said ALSO because the location of your variable definition isn't the only mistake in the script if you want to have a multiline hotkey.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I now have moved ``Reload`` to its own line, in my production script. To keep context in this superuser page, I'll Keep my original code as is.